# How to find the general formula of simple power series'

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I have these two parts of two different power series. If the question asks to find the radius of convergence, I know how to do it; however I never know how to generate the general form of power series if I am not given it (and instead I am just given the first n terms)
[image]

Is there a way how to create the general formula if I am given the first several terms?
Thank you!

Comment: Isn't it obvious in both cases?  Note:  there's no way to *prove* that the obvious general formula is the intended pattern, but in cases like this it's usually expected that you'll just go with the obvious.

Comment: @lulu for me it's not obvious, I never see it :/

Comment: Just write out the coefficients as a sequence.  In the first, we get $\{\frac 1{0!}, \frac 1{1!}, \frac 1{2!}, \frac 1{3!}, \cdots\}$.  Now can you spot the pattern?

Comment: @lulu got it now! (I think) is it series from n=0 to infinity in a form of (x^n)/n! ? I didnt know that writing the coefficient would help so much, thank you!